# Using Resolve In AngularJS Routes to get Json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get Json data in AngularJS Routes and then inject it to the controller. A resolve contains one or more promises that must resolve successfully before the route will change. This means you can wait for data to become available before showing a view, and simplify the initialization of the model inside a controller because the initial data is given to the controller instead of the controller needing to go out and fetch the data.

For some reason it does not work and I received this error message:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=bookListAsJsonProvider%20%3C-%20bookListAsJson%20%3C-%20appController

Any ideas please?

**routeProvider:**

```js
booksApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "booksTemplate.html",
        controller : "appController",
        resolve: {
             bookListAsJson: function($http, $q){
                var deferedObj = $q.defer();
                var dataURL = 'http://localhost:8080/BooksWebApp/data.json';
                $http.get(dataURL)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        deferedObj.resolve(data);
                });
                return deferedObj.promise;
             }
         }
     })
});
```

**Controller:**

```js
booksApp.controller('appController', function ($scope, bookListAsJson, prompt) {
```

Comment: do you have more than one instance of that controller in the view? Such as  `<div ng-controller="appController">`

Comment: Why are you going through the hassle of creating a whole new promise with `$q.defer()`, whereas you could just simply `return $http.get(...)`?

Comment: No, I have just one instance. and I can't just simply return $http.get(...) because I need the promised data injects into the controller AFTER it resolves.

Comment: No, you can return the $http promise as @SinDeus says. It will be injected to the controller in the same way. You just have to use bookListAsJson.data in your controller.

Comment: You could then do: `resolve: function ($http) { return $http.get(...).then(function (response) { return response.data; }); }`

Comment: Thanks, All. The problem was solved. I have just deleted the controller from the HTML template and now it's work perfectly.